# Footer doesnt show with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS stylesheet showing its correct position

```
#header {
    background-color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(../GFX/Web-Banner.png);
}
#content {
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 125px;
}
#navigation {
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 600px;
}
.maintext {
    font-family: "Futura LT Light";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #000;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the footer not showing ( the color of the footer is grey )
[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Josh Taylor</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">Content for  id "header" Goes Here
<div id="navigation">Content for  id "navigation" Goes Here</div>
</div>
<div id="content">Content for  id "content" Goes Here</div>
<div class="footer">Content for  class "footer" Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any HTML to go with that? And if this CSS shows the correct position, where is the one that is incorrect?

Comment: A fidler would help.

Comment: You don't need to be using position:absolute on any of these elements. You generally shouldn't be using absolute positioning to layout a website. If you remove position:absolute and the top and left positioning from all of your elements, they will stack on top of each other. If you need elements to float beside each other look into CSS Floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in HTML: make footer as id="footer"

Comment: I'm sure this inspired a major head slap :)

Comment: @Ted ha ha ha sometimes it happens Bro. 
Problems can be solved with small solutions but we are so messed with problem that simple solution doesn't come in our mind

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used `class='footer'` in your html and set the css for the id footer, so this body should work:

```
<body>
        <div id="header">Content for id "header" Goes Here
            <div id="navigation">Content for id "navigation" Goes Here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">Content for id "content" Goes Here</div>
        <div id="footer">Content for class "footer" Goes Here</div>
</body>
```